# Is there still any problems running MongoDB or Redis under OpenVZ?

Tags: mongodb, redis, high-load, openvz

Some tutorials says it's not recommended. Does problems still actual?

Comment: For MongoDB the warning relates to performance and stability issues in older versions of OpenVZ (i.e. circa 2010/2011, or roughly RHEL5 and earlier). More recent kernel+OpenVZ version (i.e. 2013+) are apparently fine. What specific O/S & kernel version are you using?